# Tweaking POCOs generated by EF Reverse Engineer

Tags: entity-framework, code-generation, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-classes

I'm generating POCOs from my db via EF Power Tools and am ready to start tweaking and extending them.

[This Q/A gets me past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619609/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-attributes-to-auto-generated-entities-using-vs2010) the initial question (how to add partials) but I wonder if the provided answer will have changed for MVC4 projects.

But that answer pertains specifically to validation. I also need to tweak the generated constructors - similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475469/adding-code-to-entity-framework-4-generated-pocos). My db schema the utility constructs my user object like so:

```
    public User()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
        this.Emails = new List<Email>();
        this.Institutions = new List<Institution>();
        this.Orders = new List<Order>();
        this.Phones = new List<Phone>();
    }
```

With the exception of Institutions, these would all be correct. A user can have many phones, emails and so on. But can only belong to one Institution.

I would presume there's no way to re-wire this constructor such that a List of Institution is not created. So I'd create a method that adds a 'Institution' (singular) property and assign Institutions.SingleOrDefault and perhaps some flagging/handling on .Count>1?

So a constructor on my partial class would behavior the same as on the generated class? It runs on a new up?

thx

To follow-up re: the FKs that are behind the code gen. My Institution can have many users and keys back to the primary contact based on 'PrimaryContact' via the Users identity field.

Institution:
CONSTRAINT [FK_Institutions_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([idPrimaryContact]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])

User:
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Institutions] FOREIGN KEY ([idUserInstitution]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Institutions] ([ID])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EF power tools is creating this relationship, because the database allows a User to have multiple institutions.  I assume this is because there is a FK of UserId on your Institution table.  If this is truly a 1:1 or 1:0.1 relationship, maybe you should change the database so that the User table has a FK to the Institution table instead (nullable if it's optional).

If this is not an option then there are some other ways to do this:

Are you needing to be able to do this in a templated fashion or on just this single entity?

If you're needing to do this repeatedly, you might want to try altering the TT files that generate the entity objects.  [Rowan Miller had an excellent post](http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/) about this.

Either way, you could modify your item like this:

```
 public virtual List<Institution> Institutions { get; set; }

public Institution Institution
{
    get { return Institutions.SingleOrDefault(); }
}
```

Then just bind to the Institution property you created.

Comment: +1 for the link to a current link to the subject of T4 templates - and specific to Power Tools as well.